# Making a datagrid in zend framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2

I am looking for software which creates a DataGrid in ZF2. I've found odiaseo/zf2-datagrid from GitHub but I currently do not understand how to use it. Does anyone have any suggestions on where I can find a tutorial with step-by-step instructions?

Answer (score 1):

Step by step installation and usage guide is already there on git.

https://github.com/odiaseo/zf2-datagrid

I don't know what type of suggestions you need. but you can find good comparison of zf2 with other frameworks. one of them is [here](http://www.idipous.net/symfony2-vs-zend-framework-2-through-the-eyes-of-a-novice/)

Have you tried using [this](http://datatables.net/)

Comment: I follow the all process which was given there but that's not working properly i am using that 'USAGE' section in my module 'Album' to changing controller and view but there is given error please give me process how it will use in my Album module?

Answer (score 1):

There are some other datagrids for zf2 as well. Try one that fits your need

see here: http://modules.zendframework.com/?query=datagrid

e.g. https://github.com/ThaDafinser/ZfcDatagrid